# R programming issue

Tags: r

```
str <- "[0,1,3,4,23,13]"
val <- gsub('[|]', '', str);  # 
xi <- unlist(strsplit(val, '[,]'));
```

When I parse string "[0,1,3,4,23,13]". The expectation is to have this result "0"  "1"   "3"   "4"   "23"  "13" - meaning that
I want to remove these characters "[", "]" and ",". But when I try to run that code above, it can not remove "[", "]" characters.
Can anyone help me to fix it ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code just missing some letter, because of your mistake in gsub() function. You just need to slightly edit that code below

```
str <- "[0,1,3,4,23,13]"
val <- gsub('[[]|[]]', '', str);  # [[]|[]]
xi <- unlist(strsplit(val, '[,]'));
```

It work well and will give you expectation result.